# Calculations involving thresholds between two tables

Tags: mysql, join, datetime, condition, decimal

I have a table `comment` and a table `price` like below. The key columns in both tables are `ticker_id`, `price_datetime` and `price_open`. The last column `threshold` in table `comment` (which currently NULL) is something that I need to fill in with after some calculation queries (if this is achievable).

`comment` table:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| comment_id | comment_datetime    | author | comment | ticker_id | price_datetime      | price_open | threshold |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1          | 2014-09-22 06:05:00 | A1     | C1      | 343       | 2014-09-22 08:00:00 | 53.25000   |           |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 2          | 2014-09-22 06:39:00 | A2     | C2      | 1         | 2014-09-22 08:00:00 | 62.00000   |           |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 3          | 2014-09-22 08:13:00 | A3     | C3      | 178       | 2014-09-22 08:13:00 | 5.15000    |           |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

`price` table:

```
+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| price_id | price_datetime      | price_open | ticker_id |
+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1        | 2014-09-22 08:01:00 | 62.00000   | 1         |
+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 2        | 2014-09-22 08:02:00 | 62.00000   | 1         |
+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 3        | 2014-09-22 08:03:00 | 62.00000   | 1         |
+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

In each row of table `comment`, `price_open` will be used as "base price".

- For each row of table `comment`

  - Match the `ticker_id`, `price_datetime` and `price_open` with table `price`
  - Then, get the +-2 days for each `price_datetime` (follows with the `price_open`)
  - Then, count whether any of the `price.price_open` within that 5 days exceeds 5%, 10% or 15% of the "base price"
- Conditions:

  - If any of the `price.price_open` within that 5 days equals/exceeds 15% of the "base price", then fill in `comment.threshold` with "R"
  - If any of the `price.price_open` within that 5 days equals/exceeds 10% of the "base price" (but less than 15%), then fill in `comment.threshold` with "A"
  - If any of the `price.price_open` within that 5 days equals/exceeds 5% of the "base price" (but less than 10%), then fill in `comment.threshold` with "Y"
  - If any of the `price.price_open` within that 5 days is less 5%, then fill in `comment.threshold` with "C"
  - For empty values in columns `comment.price_datetime` and `comment.price_open`, we will leave it NULL as it is, thus NULL for `comment.threshold` as well.

Is the above going to be achievable in MySQL using JOIN? I am trying to learn about JOIN right now, unfortunately it seems way too complicated to me, I have no clue about the query that I should execute as I just started learning MySQL.

I've tried explaining my question in details, but if there's anything unclear, kindly let me know.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT** (as requested by Verace):

`CREATE` statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `ticker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_open` decimal(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `threshold` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `price_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_open` decimal(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`price_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `datetime` (`price_datetime`,`ticker_id`)
)
```

Expected result:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| comment_id | comment_datetime    | author | comment | ticker_id | price_datetime      | price_open | threshold |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1          | 2014-09-22 06:05:00 | A1     | C1      | 343       | 2014-09-22 08:00:00 | 53.25000   |     C     |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 2          | 2014-09-22 06:39:00 | A2     | C2      | 1         | 2014-09-22 08:00:00 | 62.00000   |     Y     |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 3          | 2014-09-22 08:13:00 | A3     | C3      | 178       | 2014-09-22 08:13:00 | 5.15000    |     R     |
+------------+---------------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: @Vérace here's the pastebin links for both tables. `price` has got millions of rows, so i randomly pick only 1000. As for the `comment` table in the question, it's actually a simplified model, so the pastebin link i give you is actually the full model. https://pastebin.com/DRsAgqeq and https://pastebin.com/yDncBzCm

Comment: There's a problem with your pastebin - you chose random samples from your tables - there's no way to match up the records with each other. Secondly, your conditions are very complex. It's possible that a stored procedure could do what you want - I have a feeling it's not possible through SQL, at least with MySQL. If you could change to PostgreSQL, it's much more powerful (CTE's, Windowing  functions) - you did say that you just started this work. Or if you're handy with PHP/Python/whatever, that could do the trick. Also, I'm an English speaker and I'm still confused, sorry :-(

Comment: I think I should use C# approach (although it's not handy, I think I better move on rather than stuck here).

Comment: It could be better in the long run to do things properly at the beginning - you will learn more and you'll ultimately become a better database programmer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is not the be-all and end-all of programming languages.  I would not try to do this in SQL, rather do it in some other language (Perl, PHP, Java, VB, etc).

A minor nit on the indexes of `price`.  Is price_id ever used?  Consider DROPping it and turning the UNIQUE KEY into the PRIMARY KEY.